# How to generate a rotating electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

Does it involve the use of any magnets? And if so is there a geometric centre where the resultant field is zero.

Comment: What do you mean by a rotating electric field?

Comment: Depending on what you actually want, you could just spin a charged capacitor around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily produce a rotating electric field
by adding an oscillating field in $x$ direction
and an oscillating field in $y$ direction,
both with a phase difference of 90° between each other.

$$ \begin{pmatrix}E_x\\ E_y\\ E_z \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}\hat{E} \cos \omega t\\ \hat{E} \sin \omega t\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

This field is homogenous in space. So there is no geometric
center where it is always zero.

For generating it you just need an AC voltage supply, a phase shifter,
two pairs of metal plates, and some cables.